# как найти максимальное число в словаре и выводило 1 или несколько ключей с такими значениями

Tags: python

```
Items = {
    'Iphone 12': {'price': 600, 'Count': 12},
    'Iphone 12 pro': {'price': 700, 'Count': 17},
    'Iphone 12 pro max': {'price': 800, 'Count': 3},
    'Iphone 13': {'price': 900, 'Count': 18},
    'Iphone 13 pro': {'price': 1000, 'Count': 22},
    'Iphone 13 pro max': {'price': 1100, 'Count': 8},
    'Iphone 14': {'price': 1200, 'Count': 25},
    'Iphone 14 pro': {'price': 1300, 'Count': 13},
    'Iphone 14 pro max': {'price': 1400, 'Count': 25}
}
```

мне нужен вывод (Iphone 14 Count: 25}, Iphone 14 pro max Count 25}

Comment: вы циклы изучали?

Comment: Нам нужна ваша попытка решения, которая не привела к желаемому результату.

Comment: да, но всё же не получается

Comment: Добро пожаловать в StackOverflow! Вопросы должны также содержать попытки автора решить задачу, без них (попыток) вопрос будет являться задачей. Подробнее [в Справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error).

Comment: Я верю в то что вы потратили не один час на попытку это решить и просто забыли добавить попытку вашего решения, максимальное имеется ввиду модель телефона?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой Вариант:

```
x = dict(sorted(Items.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['Count'], reverse=True))
curr = -1
for key, val in x.items():
    if curr <= val['Count']:
        print(f"{key}: Count: {val['Count']}")
        curr = val['Count']
```

Вывод:

```
Iphone 14: Count: 25
Iphone 14 pro max: Count: 25
```